# Kafka connector "Unable to connect to the server" - dockerized kafka-connect worker that connects to confluent cloud

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-cloud

I'm following similar example as in this blog post:

https://rmoff.net/2019/11/12/running-dockerised-kafka-connect-worker-on-gcp/

Except that I'm not running kafka connect worker on GCP but locally.

Everything is fine I run the docker-compose up and kafka connect starts but when I try to create instance of source connector via CURL I get the following ambiguous message (Note: there is literally no log being outputed in the kafka connect logs):

```
{"error_code":400,"message":"Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s):\nUnable to connect to the server.\nYou can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/{connectorType}/config/validate`"}
```

I know I can connect to confluent cloud because I see that there are topics being created:

```
docker-connect-configs  
docker-connect-offsets  
docker-connect-status
```

My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```yaml
---
  version: '2'
  services:
      
        kafka-connect-01:
          image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.4.0
          container_name: kafka-connect-01
          restart: always
          depends_on:
            # - zookeeper
            # - kafka
            - schema-registry
          ports:
            - 8083:8083
          environment:
            CONNECT_LOG4J_APPENDER_STDOUT_LAYOUT_CONVERSIONPATTERN: "[%d] %p %X{connector.context}%m (%c:%L)%n"
            CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "my-server-name.confluent.cloud:9092"
            CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
            CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "kafka-connect-01"
            CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
            CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
            CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
            CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
            #CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
            CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://my-server-name.confluent.cloud:8081'
            #CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
            CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://my-server-name.confluent.cloud:8081'
            CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
            CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
            CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: "INFO"
            CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest=WARN,org.reflections=ERROR"
            CONNECT_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "3"
            CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "3"
            CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "3"
            CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "3"
            CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: '/usr/share/java'
            CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
            CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
            #ENV VARS FOR CCLOUD CONNECTION
            CONNECT_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM: "https"
            CONNECT_SASL_MECHANISM: PLAIN
            CONNECT_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: SASL_SSL
            CONNECT_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG: "${SASL_JAAS_CONFIG}"
            CONNECT_CONSUMER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: SASL_SSL
            CONNECT_CONSUMER_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM: https
            CONNECT_CONSUMER_SASL_MECHANISM: PLAIN
            CONNECT_CONSUMER_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG: "${SASL_JAAS_CONFIG}"
            CONNECT_PRODUCER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: SASL_SSL
            CONNECT_PRODUCER_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM: https
            CONNECT_PRODUCER_SASL_MECHANISM: PLAIN
            CONNECT_PRODUCER_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG: "${SASL_JAAS_CONFIG}"
    
          volumes:
            - db-leach:/db-leach/
            - $PWD/connectors:/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/jars/
          command: 
            - /bin/bash
            - -c
```

I have dockerized mongo instances running and I want to create mongo source connector, this is my CURL request:

```sh
    curl -X PUT http://localhost:8083/connectors/my-mongo-source-connector/config -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
    "tasks.max":"1",
    "connector.class":"com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector",
    "connection.uri":"mongodb://mongo1:27017,mongo2:27017,mongo3:27017",
    "topic.prefix":"topic.prefix",
    "topic.suffix":"mySuffix",
    "database":"myMongoDB",
    "collection":"myMongoCollection",
    "copy.existing": "true",
    "output.format.key": "json",
    "output.format.value": "json",
    "change.stream.full.document": "updateLookup",
    "publish.full.document.only": "false",
    "confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers" : "'${CCLOUD_BROKER_HOST}':9092", 
    "confluent.topic.sasl.jaas.config" : "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"'${CCLOUD_API_KEY}'\" password=\"'${CCLOUD_API_SECRET}'\";", 
    "confluent.topic.security.protocol": "SASL_SSL", 
    "confluent.topic.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm": "https", 
    "confluent.topic.sasl.mechanism": "PLAIN" 
    }';
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it to work, this is a correct configuration...

The message "Unable to connect to the server" was because I had wrongly deployed mongo instance so it's not related to kafka-connect or confluent cloud.

I'm going to leave this question as an example if somebody struggles with this in the future. It took me a while to figure out how to configure docker-compose for kafka-connect that connects to confluent cloud.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your current answer with some more information?

Comment: @AdarshBalu what do you want to know? It's an example of dockerized kafka-connect configuration that connects to kafka instance hosted on confulent cloud. It's really specific configuration only if you're using kafka instance running on confluent cloud if not then configuration is different.

Comment: What do u mean by wrongly deployed? What was wrong?

Comment: @BorisIvanov I don't remember exactly but I'm pretty sure I ran mongo as docker image so probably some configuration was wrong or something like that...

Comment: Yeah seems mongo was not started properly